# What is the purpose of OrientDb's port ranges when running an embedded server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, orientdb, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running an embedded OrientDb. We're using Spring/Spring Data and we have JUnit tests running via Maven's Surefire plugin.

The embedded database gets started before every test. I'd like to somehow change this so that it would get loaded once per Maven module's execution, if possible.

I had the following:

```
OServerNetworkListenerConfiguration binaryListener = new OServerNetworkListenerConfiguration();
binaryListener.ipAddress = "0.0.0.0";
binaryListener.portRange = "2424-2430";
binaryListener.protocol = "binary";
binaryListener.socket = "default";
```

Obviously, due to the amount of tests, 6 ports are insufficient and I get this cryptic error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project bar-api: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /java/foo/bar/bar-api && /java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -jar /java/foo/bar/bar-api/target/surefire/surefirebooter3262843936755308263.jar /java/foo/bar/bar-api/target/surefire/surefire2085279380429297504tmp /java/foo/bar/bar-api/target/surefire/surefire_53552629494142788284tmp
```

There is no `System.exit()` anywhere in my code, but the Maven Surefire plugin exits the build.

My questions are: why the need for so many ports? Can't it just use one? What am I missing out here and how to fix it? (For the time-being, I have simply increased the number of ports, as a temporary workaround, but I'd really like to get a better understanding of the issue and sort it out properly).

Answer (score 2):

When a server instance starts it tries to bind the listener to the first unused port in that range. So you can't use the same port for two different server instances.

Comment: Yeah, but when a test is done, I would assume that the database is shutdown, right? How is it running out of ports?